# What is the best way to make money?

Tags: the-witcher-3

This is my first Witcher game and I need to pay 1000 gold to get to Skellige. Everything I sell goes for dirt cheap. Ie. Sword's selling for 20 gold etc.

What is the best way to make money ?

Comment: My guess is that it's because it's so easy to amass huge stockpiles of things, having them sell for lots of money would make it too easy to get rich. Either way this question as it is sounds like it's asking for developer intent, which we can't answer. If you change the question to focus on "how do I make more money", you'd probably get better answers

Comment: @Pyritie That's basically what he's asking, and is in the question body. His title just isn't that great, so I've edited it to better reflect what the question body.

Comment: [Just going to put this here...](http://kotaku.com/grim-witcher-3-money-exploit-leaves-dead-cows-everywher-1706153778)

Comment: @Thebluefish Was just reading about that. Massive exploit, but 'handy'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Steal everything, there is so much stuff lying around. You can take anything without any problems as long as there isn't a guard in sight. Enable your Witcher vision and just loot anything that is highlighted. Most items still only give you small amounts of coin, but you'll find a lot of them and it'll sum up.

Fistfighting pays reasonably well, I could bet 100 crowns and even against high level enemies the fights were pretty easy.

You probably can safely sell certain alchemy ingredients if you have many of them, but I can't absolutely guarantee that you won't need them. But who really needs dozens of drowner brains?

But if you don't have 1000 gold yet, maybe you shouldn't start to sail to Skellige just yet. You'll earn quite a bit of money just by doing side quests and contracts, and looting everything in sight.

Comment: Witcher contract pays around 250-300 crowns each!

Comment: Where can I sell stuff in Witcher 3? Items show up as "cannot be sold".

Comment: @Myth17 Not every merchant buys everything, just try a few different ones. Blacksmiths and Armorsmiths generally buy weapons and armor, Herbalists buy alchemy items, ...

Comment: I keep a stock of 10 when it comes to ingredients and I sell everything over that initial 10.

Comment: @DavidYell that's a good idea, actually!

Answer (score 3):

I've got a goodN for ya but you've gotta have access to Novigrad. Specifically Hierarch Square In Novigrad. Once ya get there locate the merchant standing near his booth and buy all of his seashells. (He'll have 2 kinds of seashells, get'em all!) After buying him out close the trade by saying farewell and then reopen the trade.. The shell will restock after every 'farewell' so When you're satisfied with the amount you have or when your cash-flow starts getting light head to the Armorer who's shop is just a few steps away.. (need to have some $$ left for next step) Use the Armorer to dismantle all the shells (worth $4 and $8) leaving you with a grip of pearls which are now worth $109 and $142 to the Armorer. Now comes the fast cash!! Sell him as many pearls as he can afford before ending the trade. Now that you have all his money you'll need to meditate for a minimum of 5 days before he'll have another thousand or so to spend on more pearls.. Repeating this method of selling pearls then meditating will stack some serious loot and FAST! Only takes a minute or less to do the whole 'sell then meditate' process which adds another 1,000 or so to your wallet each time.. fastest and easiest way I've come across yet!! Shit, I ended up with 8k going on 10k in a matter of minutes!!  Hopefully my lack of sleep hasn't made this explanation too confusing to follow! lol... Enjoy!!
    Make money money, go shopping!!
      Take money money, go shopping!!

I found this method online days ago so props to the Og who first posted this!

Comment: Btw, this beats the FUGG outa that cow killin method!!!!! lol..

Comment: Am I the only one who (oddly, maybe) finds this method to be unethical?

Comment: Only slightly unethical, and it's not nearly as unethical as save scumming, for example.

Answer (score 2):

I had 5k by the time I was level 10. At level 15 I'm sitting on 10k, all from looting enemies and selling excess supplies and gear to the right merchants; though sometimes to whatever merchant just to save time. (I keep 20 of an ingredient and keep most strong alcohol).

I've probably sold 500 or more swords, thinking about it that way I've probably killed more people than any ten men on either side of the war. Lol 500 x 6 (lowball average) = 3000. The little things add up. Some sold around 100 or even 200, and that's not counting armor sales.

I thought the same thing early on because there were a few things I wanted to buy, but then I started finding better gear and crafting better gear so I saved the money. I go for significant upgrades only. Buying armor or weapons for a measly +10 isn't worth it.

If my memory serves me well I believe all of this witcher games have a similar economic system. Poor in the beginning, and no worries from the middle onward if you are frugal or don't blow it unneccessarily.

Answer (score 0):

In FREYA'S GARDEN, on Hindarsfjall, there is a werewolf named Morkvarg (part of the main quest "Nameless" or the secondary quest "In Wolf's Clothing").  This werewolf spawns infinitely in his cave (meditate 3-4 hours each time and your meditation will be broken with him attacking you).  95% of the time he drops a Werewolf Hide (192), Werewolf Saliva (60), Monster Essence (15), and Werewolf Meat (1).  At level 15 I could kill him in under 20 seconds each (plus 10 seconds or so for the meditation) which means 30 seconds for every 300-ish crowns.

They haven't patched this exploit yet (as nobody has posted it yet that I could find), so have fun while you can before they make Morkvarg get stronger each time he dies or force a gigantic dragon on you after 10 kills or something, lol!  I just spent an hour killing him 50 times.  Now I just need to figure out where I can get more bang for my buck selling the mats.

EDIT:

To get the most bang for your buck selling your werewolf parts, go to the docks at the north end of Novigrad, where you will find a beggar selling bottles.  This beggar buys anything for its FULL VALUE.  Buy all his bottles so that he has some coin to give you back (they cost 1, sell for 1), then sell some werewolf parts, escape out, and ask him what he has for sale again.  He will be COMPLETELY RESTOCKED ON BOTTLES.  Rinse and repeat.  Go to your favorite merchant who buys bottles and is loaded with coin and sell all your bottles for the same price you paid for them, thus giving you FULL VALUE for your werewolf parts.

Answer (score 0):

**There is money a plenty!**

First, sell your looted stuff to the right buyer: An armourer will pay better for armour, a sword smith for swords, etc...

Not that alchemical ingredients are very valuable and can be sold for huge amount to the any herbalist or armourer/smith. You can easily get a thousand crowns by selling one or two sapphire/ruby/diamond dusts. Most times, the merchants will run out of money before you can sell it all.

Books can be sold for large amounts in Novigrad to the book merchant off the main square.

Food and drinks can be sold in inns and taverns or you know, just eaten when Geralt is injured.

Old coins can be exchanged for crowns at the bank in Novigrad.

Runes are a fantastic source of money. Chances are, you will use only a few. The rest, you should sell. Sure, when you get the right recipes you can upgrades them but in the mean time, sell! Right there, you might make a few thousands.

There are lots of hidden treasures, guarded treasures, and smugglers caches dotted around. Most are marked as "?" on your map. It is really worth looking at those for both loot, XPs, and fun side quests.

In Heart Of Stone, you need around 25,000 crowns for a quest. Getting that amount of money using the above took me about an hour of game play.

Answer (score -4):

You can watch this

I hope it works

Comment: you should describe the content of the video. if Youtube or the uploader takes it down your answer will be useless